# How to perform substring search using elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `green elephant` in the elastic and I want to match first two comments from the `queries`: `green elephant is here` and `white and green elephant`

```
await self.upload_to_elastic('green elephant')

queries = ('green elephant is here',
           'white and green elephant',
           'white and green and gray elephant'
           'elephant green',
           'green is my elephant name',
           'green',
           'green elephants')

for query in queries:
    items = await service.search_by_phrase(query)
```

What is the way of doing this substring search?

Comment: Have you looked at NGRAMS? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html

Comment: is this the only way to achieve what I want? what if there is a restriction that items in the elastic search consist only from 1 word (so, not `green elephant`, but just `green` or `elephant`)

Comment: From my experience ngrams is the easiest why to-do what i think you want todo. And yes ngrams will cater for the 1 word scenario.

Answer (score 0):

If your query is for the value in the `message` field, you can just use `regexp`:

```
{
    "query": {
        "regexp":{
            "message": {
                "value": ".*(green elephant).*"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [phrase matching](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) with a slop of 0 (which is the default) to match only consecutive terms in the right order.

```
GET /_search
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "message" : "green elephant"
        }
    }
}
```

The regexp query approach is functional but non-viable in production since regexp queries are really resource-consuming.

Comment: I already have `green elephant` in elastic, look at the list of `queries `

Comment: Sorry, i misread your question. You can use regexp or shingle (like ngrams but for phrase) for your case